# using ctags to get class inheritance

Tags: c++, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm trying to get ctags to output a C++ class hierarchy, but it seems to struggle with multiple inheritance (or even single inheritance sometimes).

e.g:

```
class Fred 
: public BaseFred
{

}; 

class John: public BaseJohn,
    public BaseFred
{

};


ctags -N -x  --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+i+k CtagsTest.cpp 
Fred             class         1 CtagsTest.cpp    class Fred 
John             class         7 CtagsTest.cpp    class John: public BaseJohn,
```

Where is BaseFred?

ctags V5.8 misses multiple inheritance in both (valid) cases.

Is there a better tool?

Comment: Not sure if there are better tools, but if you use Doxygen and output to xml you can find all the inheritance data you need, and lots more.

Answer (score 0):

By default, -x doesn't print "inherits" even if you specifiy --fields=+i option.

Universal-ctag (https://ctags.io) may help you.
It has `--_xformat` option.

```
[jet@living]/tmp% ~/var/ctags/ctags -x --_xformat="%N => %i" foo.cc
~/var/ctags/ctags -x --_xformat="%N => %i" foo.cc
Fred => BaseFred
John => BaseJohn,BaseFred
```

`--_xformat` is explained in http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/news.html?highlight=--_xformat#customizing-xref-output .